# How can I print a message stored in a buffer?

Tags: while-loop, console, break, uart

I am trying to write a function called SerialSend that will print the contents of a ring buffer (named testbuff) to my console.This is my definition for SerialSend.

```
void SerialSend (USInt* pusiBuffer, UDInt len, UDInt connectionId)
{
  USART_WriteByte(DEMO_USART, testbuff[i]); 
  i++;
  i %= DEMO_RING_BUFFER_SIZE;
}
```

When called, SerialSend is printing the first character in testbuff. How do I get it to print the rest of the contents of the buffer? This is the code in main where I call SerialSend and the break isn't working.

```
  while(i<17)
  {
    SerialSend(testbuff, 17, 0)  //Sends contents of testbuff to print in console
    if (i==16)
    {
      break;                     //Break isn't working, probably because i never hits 16 due to the ring
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had my ring buffer size too small, so I increased the size to 50 and editted the call in main like this:

```
while(1)
  {
    SerialSend(testbuff, 50, 0); //Sends contents of testbuff to print in console
    if (i==17)
    {
      break;
    }
  }
```

The testbuff buffer holds 17 characters  I want to print, hence the if statement for a break when the index hits the end of the message.